# Android - Camera Issue

Tags: bitmap, android-camera

I am trying to capture a photo and display it in the image view.

```
        public class next extends Activity{

         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                 setContentView(R.layout.next);         Button cbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capture); /* Capture Photo */
                    cbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v)         { 
                        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(intent,0);       }       });

             }
         @Override  
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {        
ImageView iv
         = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);   
        if(requestCode == 0)        
    {       Bitmap theImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            iv.setImageBitmap(theImage);        
}}}
```

So this is code i have done with . Now the problem is that I am getting red line under "data"

```
Bitmap theImage = (Bitmap) ***data***.getExtras().get("data");
```

And I do not the reason , Can any one please explain me what I have done wrong or any other solution to my problem ?

Comment: Could you at least try to format your question in a readable way. This would increase your chances to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `data` is neither declared no passed as parameter to your method, therefor it's marked red.

Comment: Will you please explain me about this line of code ?

Bitmap theImage = (Bitmap) ***data***.getExtras().get("data");

I have tried to study it but I could not understand it .

Comment: How can I explain you your code??? If you have copied it from somewhere, look if you find an explanation there, or search for a tutorial.

Comment: Then check the whole tutorial's code where the `data` variable is declared.

Comment: I got my mistake I have override a wrong function " startActivityForResult".Instead of this I should override onActivityResult()

Comment: I am unable to answer my question due to stackoverflow restriction , I will answer this question as I will get the rights :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem with this code was that I have override wrong method :

```
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {        
ImageView iv
         = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);   
        if(requestCode == 0)        
    {       Bitmap theImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            iv.setImageBitmap(theImage);        
}}
```

Because when result will come from the activity it displays by the following method :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


        //ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        if(requestCode == 1)
        {

        Bitmap theImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                iv.setImageBitmap(theImage);
        }
```

That's It :)

```
    }
```